# undefined reference between c++ files

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

i have this simple program in the clion editor

```
    //main.cpp
    #include "my.h"
    int main(){
        foo = 1;
        print_foo();
        return 0;
    }
```

```
    //my.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "my.h"
    void print_foo(){
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
```

```
    //my.h
    #ifndef INC_Project
        #define INC_Project 
        extern int foo;
        void print_foo();    
    #endif //INC_Project
```

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
    project(Project)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    add_executable(Project my.h my.cpp main.cpp)
```

i am getting this output

> [100%] Linking CXX executable Project
>
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/my.cpp.o: warning: relocation against `foo' in read-only section` .text'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
>
> /Project/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `foo'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/my.cpp.o: in function `print_foo()':
>
> /home/o/Documents/cpp/Project/my.cpp:6: undefined reference to `foo'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build.make:118: Project] Error 1
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/rule] Error 2
>
> make: *** [Makefile:137: Project] Error 2

Comment: You *declare* the variable `foo` (in the header file), but you never *define* it anywhere (in a source file).

Comment: Do not try and bend the `foo`, that's impossible. Instead, only try to realize the truth...there is no `foo`.